# Different template in each ng-repeat based on value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-include

I've got an ng-repeat that is rendering values from items in a collection.  Depending on the type of value (i.e., link, phone number, or text), I want to conditionally add a specific template for the rendering (an `<a href` if it's a link, a formatted number if it's a phone number, etc.).  I've got inline templates in the html file as such:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="linkValue">
    <a href="#/{{itemType}}/Detail/{{id}}">{{value}}</a>
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="phoneValue">
    {{value | phone}}
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="textValue">
    {{value}}
</script>
```

I figured I'd use ng-include to render the template depending on the type of the value being rendered, but I can't figure out how to wire it up.  I've got

```
<td ng-repeat="column in columns">
    <span ng-include="???"></span>                            
</td>
```

And then in my controller I have

```
$scope.renderValue = function (columnInfo, dataItem) {
    if (columnInfo.isPhoneNumber) {
        return phoneValue;
    }
    else if (columnInfo.isDetailViewLink) {
        return linkValue
    }
    else {
        return textValue
    }               
};
```

I can't figure out how to wire up the temaplate differently for each instance of the repeated ng-include.  Is there a better way to do this?  I get the feeling there is.

Comment: but why don't you use <a> tag with href attr? if value is this, then url is this.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your questin, but I'm not always rendering links, so the <a> tag would not always be present.  I'm not just rendering dynamic links, I'm rendering completely different content some of which might be links.

Comment: You could build a custom filter that uses regex to determine the best return string.  Though, it is likely that more advanced DOM manipulations will be desired -- if that is the case then I would build a directive that parses a datamodel with the value, representationType

Comment: Yea, I definately don't want html in a controller.  That's kind of the whole point.  =]

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the wireup and you can see the result at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sonicblis/6wDkg/)

Assuming the scope has values something like this:

```
$scope.items = [
    {Id: 1, Name: "One", Email: "one@domain.com", PhoneNumber: "1234567", Roles: ["Admin", "Chief"]},
    {Id: 1, Name: "Two", Email: "two@domain.com", PhoneNumber: "7572345678", Roles: ["Member"]},
    {Id: 1, Name: "Three", Email: "three@domain.com", PhoneNumber: "3456789", Roles: ["Member", "Staff"]}
];

$scope.columns = [
    { Title: 'Name', Property: 'Name', type: 'link' },
    { Title: 'Primary Email', Property: 'Email', type: 'mail' },
    { Title: 'Phone', Property: 'PhoneNumber', type: 'phone' },
    { Title: 'Roles', Property: 'Roles', type: 'array' }        
];
```

I can define a gettemplate function like this:

```
$scope.getTemplate = function(type){
    if (type)
        return type + 'Value';
    else
        return 'textValue';
};
```

By setting the ng-include to the getTeamplate $scope function and returning a string that matches the id attribute of a template, the ng-include will load that template and interpolate any angular tags/content in the scope of the controller into which it was included.

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items">
    <td ng-repeat="column in columns">                
        <span ng-include="getTemplate(column.type)"></span>                
    </td>
</tr>
```

and the templates were changed to reference the scope of the ng-repeat in which they were to be included:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="linkValue">
    <a href="/#">{{item[column.Property]}}</a>
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="mailValue">
    <a href="mailto:{{item[column.Property]}}">{{item[column.Property]}}</a>
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="phoneValue">
    {{formatAsPhone(item[column.Property])}}
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="textValue">
    just a value
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="arrayValue">
    {{item[column.Property].join(", ")}}
</script>
```